# Mysql - Insert queries inserting funny characters

Tags: php, sql, mysql, character-encoding

I have a simple script which inserts values from a text file into a mysqldatabase - however some accented characters aren't inserted properly. Like lets say I have a word:

Reykjavík

I try to insert it using a simple insert sql statement and instead I this value ends up in the database????

ReykjavÃ­k

How do I fix this?

====EDIT====

I tried to change the collation - the thing is that I'm using navicat here and if I lets say try to insert any such word with accentuated characters like this using the navicat QUery generator or panel it is inserted perfectly with no problem whatso ever - however my php script when it runs a similar query end s up putting trash in the table :( whats going on here...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The set of questions marks is because you are inserting a character whose encoding is not understood by MySQL. Try collating with utf8_bin. This should work.

Comment: Make sure the php encoding is set to UTF8